# .NET 4.0 Integrated Pipeline for MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My app works fine when NOT using integrated pipeline.

How can I debug my app on the server when using integrated pipeline?

I can't even get a controller to initialize--it never gets to it (discovered via logging).

I'm using the facebook sdk and Unity, if that makes any difference.

Comment: So does it run on your development machine in integrated mode?

Comment: I'm using the virtual server to run it locally.

Comment: Well run it on IIS locally then. On the server you can go to debug > attach to process and hook the VS debugger to the IIS process but you will need VS on the machine.